# PixelBlock alternative for Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, security, firefox, privacy

I'm using Firefox 57. I'm looking for software that blocks the 1x1 pixels that cause the HTTP{S} fetches that are used to track users. The product I used in the past is called PixelBlock. I searched Firefox add-ons, but I did not find it.

The add-on search returned about 650+ results. I visited the top hits and the functionality was not described in the add-on's descriptions. For example, the number one hit when searching for *"PixelBlock"* (with quotes) returned *uBlock Origin*, and it does not appear to provide the blocking (based on the product details).

A second requirement is, I want something that requires a minimum set of permissions. I don't want software that takes full control of the computer just to block the HTTP request generated by a tracking pixel.

What is the recommendation for software that blocks the small pixels, like 1x1 and 3x3, which advertisers and data harvesters use to track users?

---

I've been kind of laxed of late, and I have not been using the blocking technology. [How Email Open Tracking Quietly Took Over the Web](https://www.wired.com/story/how-email-open-tracking-quietly-took-over-the-web/) brought back the desire to run the defensive software.

Comment: uBlock Origin not only blocks those tracking pixels, but a bunch of other trackers as well. But it works rather by URLs than by element sizes :)

Comment: You can't know picture size until you download it. And if you did, you are already tracked and it's too late to block it. So I don't understand what you are asking about.

Comment: PixelBlock is a Gmail extension not a Firefox Add-on.

Comment: To clarify Izzy's comment:  Generic content blockers, like the one he mentioned, can block tracking pixels, if and only if those images are somehow specified in a filter list (often by URL).

Comment: I just tested and uBlock Origin does not block Mixmax tracked emails.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly Email is probably what you are looking for

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ugly-email-com/

Answer (score 0):

##### [ScriptSafe-FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptsafe-ff/)

Those 1×1 tracking pixels AKA "web bugs" or "[web beacons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon)" are blocked by default by ScriptSafe (among other tracking content). To toggle, click the ScriptSafe toolbar button → Options → Privacy Settings → Remove Webbugs.

---

Also, note that [**uBlock Origin**](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) ([Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) / [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)) (while not exactly what you described) can block many trackers, including most 1×1 tracking pixels. In uBO settings → Filter Lists, enable all the filters in the Privacy section to block tracking content.